# How DB Context works

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Really stuck with an MVC app.

I have a db context like this:

```
public class DataBaseContext : DbContext
{

    public DataBaseContext() : base("name = EIPInternalConnectionx")
    {

    }        
    public DbSet<LkUpGenderModel> vwLkUpGender { get; set; } 

    public DbSet<EditEmpModelView> vwEmployeeDetails { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

when it comes to runtime and the controller code is run:

such as

```
return PartialView(db.vwEmployeeDetails.ToList());
```

I get an error saying

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.EditEmpModelView'.
```

I don't want to enable migration or anything like that for it to create the table dbo.EditEmpModelView'.  I want to to look at the table in Sql called vwEmployeeDetails which is what I thought I had coded.

Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong, I have done this the same way for the Gender one and it works so I am totally confused!!

in the global.asax file i have

```
Database.SetInitializer<DataBaseContext>(null);
```

in the Application_Start()

Comment: `OnModelCreating` (in your dbcontext) you should have (at least) `modelBuilder.Entity<EditEmpModelView>().ToTable("dbo", "vwEmployeeDetails");`

Comment: Would i need that line for every table i add to the context?

I added more detail if it helps

Comment: after viewing some of the other questions you have posted about Entity Framework recently, I suspect you are a bit confused about how EF is meant to be used.  the `DbSet<T>` classes are a direct representation of the tables in your database.  you appear to be trying to use view models which may have more or less fields than your database tables; these kind of classes do not get a `DbSet<T>`; instead, you need to create a map yourself in code.

Comment: If you want to have a discussion to try to figure out what you are trying to accomplish and how to redesign your code, let me know, I'm willing to set up a chat room and make an attempt with you.

Comment: I exclusively use the chat room functions of this site when answering questions here, as the chat rooms are automatically transcribed for posterity, and the whole point of this site is providing knowledge for multiple people who may have similar issues.

Comment: I set the room up http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78214/entity-framework-discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the chat room, since you are using views to map to the models, your best course is to define a series of `DbConfigurations` to override the default Entity Framework Conventions.  Something similar to:

```
namespace DataAccess.DbConfigurations
{
public class EmployeeDetailsConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<EditEmpModelView>
{
    public EmployeeDetailsConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("vwEmployeeDetails");
        HasKey(ed => ed.EmployeeId);
    }
}
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EmployeeDetailsConfiguration());
}
```